# Show that the function is homomorphism with kernel φ

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

If $H_1,\dots, H_s$ are normal subgroups of $G$, show that the function:

$$\varphi: G\to G/H_1 \times\dots\times G/H_s$$ given by:

$$\varphi(g) = (gH_1,\dots, gH_s)$$

is a homomorphism with kernel:

$$\ker \varphi = \bigcap_{i=1}^{s}H_i.$$

I first started by proving that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism.

Given $g,h$, let's check that $\varphi(gh)=\varphi(g)\varphi(h).$

Therefore as the group operation in $\varphi$ is preserved, $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism.

Do you think I'm doing them the right way? Because from here on I'm getting a little confused about what to do.

Comment: Do the check for group hom. more carefully step by step and then check that the kernel has the structure given.

Comment: Traditionally addition notation is used for abelian groups, but since normal subgroups are mentioned the group it is unlikely that abealian groups are assumed.

Comment: Given that your cosets are written as $gH$, $G$ is not additive. You must prove $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)\phi(h)$. To prove that, you must prove that for every $H_i$, $ghH_i=gH_ihH_i$ which is trivial because $H_i$ is normal.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$, `$\varphi$` for $\varphi$, and `$H_1,\dots, H_s$` for $H_1,\dots, H_s$

Comment: Note that $A\ast B$ means something other than the direct product.

Comment: If you want direct product, then use $\times$ (`\times`) rather than $*$. The latter, as Shaun indicates, is usually understood to represent the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product). Also, one does not usually use additive notation except in the case of abelian groups. The fact that you are specifying the subgroups are normal suggests you are considering the case of arbitrary, not-necessarily-abelian groups, so you should not use $+$, you should use multiplicative notation.

Answer (score 2):

As for the kernel, note that:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker}\varphi &= \{g\in G\mid \varphi(g)=(H_1,\dots,H_s)\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid (gH_1,\dots,gH_s)=(H_1,\dots,H_s)\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid (gH_1=H_1) \wedge\dots\wedge (gH_s=H_s)\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid (g\in H_1) \wedge\dots\wedge (g\in H_s)\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid g\in \bigcap_{i=1}^sH_i)\} \\
&=\bigcap_{i=1}^sH_i
\end{alignat}
Can you justify all the equal signs?